# What happens when you call JavaConverters.asJava?

Tags: java, scala

I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.2/src/library/scala/collection/convert/Wrappers.scala). If I understand it correctly, it loops through the original collection and creates a new collection in Java, which adds additional computation time.

If my understanding is correct, then I have a follow up question:

I have an `ArrayBuffer`. If I want to use it in both Scala and Java, and avoid the `asJava` call penalty. I can think of using `Array` in Scala which is `type[]` in Java. Are there any other array/list collections that are native to both Scala and Java?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that it needs to iterate and copy all the elements.  asJava just wraps the scala collection with one that implements the appropriate Java interface and should be O(1) as far as I can tell.  IT's also possible to use any java collection from scala or scala collection from java.

Comment: For those that down-voted the question, can you please at least let me know why or correct me if I am flat out wrong? Simply down voting doesn't really help.

Comment: @puhlen Thanks for the reply. I think you're right. If you want to move your comment to the answer below, I can accept it and close this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asJava` does not require iterating and copying the collection.  It simple wraps the scala collection with a class that conforms to the java interface.

It is also possible to use any java collection from scala and any scala collection from Java.  This is not normally recommended though since the interfaces are quite different.